# Http Status Code When Downstream Validation Fails

Tags: rest, http, microservices

I have an API that charges for an order. It accepts the orderId and the amount as inputs. Then it makes a '/charge' call to the downstream, which returns a 202. Immediately after this call, it calls a '/verify' endpoint to make sure that the previous charge was successful.

Now it may happen that the charge was declined. One of the reasons for this can be that the user used an expired card. What should be the error code in this scenario?

1. As I see it, I can't send a 4xx as the request was correct for my API perspective. A bad request is something that the user can correct - In this case, he can't correct anything since the API just accepts the 'orderId' and the total amount to charge.
2. If I am sending a 5XX, then 500 does not make sense as this was not an 'unexpected condition' on my server.  I can neither send a 503 as my server was not overloaded or down for maintenance.

Currently, I am sending back a 503 with an app code that maps to: Payment verification failed.

Comment: /verify is called by my API. I can't send a 2xx as the payment was declined. The /pay operation failed.

Comment: The problem with your API is, that it does not work on resources but on method invocations. This is a strong hint that you are actually doing RPC instead of REST. If you look at how it is done on the Web you have 2 kinds of payment verification schemes, one immediate when you perform the order, in which case you can't place the order if your balance isn't appropriate, and the other separating order placement and charging. Here the order usually has its own state that is updated according to the outcome. Usually a user is notified via mail on state changes.

Comment: @RomanVottner you're right. /verify is not RESTful as I am using verbs instead of nouns. Keeping that aside however, I am following the first scheme - The user can't place the order if the payment was declined.

Comment: REST has nothing to do with URLs containing verbs or not! REST is an architectural design where the decoupling of clients from servers is the actual intent which allows servers to freely evolve in future without having to fear breaking clients. It is based around the agenda that a server will teach clients everything they need to know through form-like representations and standardized link relations attached to arbitrary URIs. REST reuses the concepts from the browseable Web, so any concepts that apply to the Web also apply to REST.

Comment: If you follow the primer approach `400 Bad Request` is for sure a feasible choice. The user can try the request with an other credit card number or with an updated expiration date or corrected password. A 5** failure, for sure, is wrong as not your server caused the problem but request.

Comment: From my API perspective, the request was valid - the orderId and the amount to charge for. How's this a bad request? What is the customer supposed to rectify?

Comment: `From my API perspective, the request was valid` How can it be valid when you've stated that no order should exist without valid charge confirmation? To a client it doesn't matter whether the reason for declination stemmed from your API or from a service your API invoked. And there are enough things that a user can do in order to fix issues. I.e. a user may have exceeded his daily limit --> resend later; Entered a wrong CCV --> correct it and reissue the request; Have not enough money available --> transfer some money to that account or pay old fees.

Comment: @RomanVottner An order can very well live with an a payment that is 'chargeable' (i.e. not charged, the state before 'charged'). All I need to verify is that an order has a valid payment attached to it (from my API's perspective).

Comment: You've stated that `The user can't place the order if the payment was declined` and that you aim for the primer way that is usually done on the Web, which will process the request in one go (even if there are hundreds of intermediary steps involved) and return a single response. Again, to a user/client it doesn't matter whether the request was processed directly from the API or went through multiple different services as long as it is just one request. If later payment is possible, you need to change your design and let a client poll for the state of an order, as simple as that

Answer (score 1):

The response of the server must always be in the context of the domain responsibility of the service

If the service "accepts" the request and that is all the requester (client) is expected to know, with the domain operation being performed asynchronously behind the scenes, it should return a 202

If the interaction is synchronous, you must surely respond with an error, since the request was unsuccessful.
The response code depends on the domain remits.

As per your service, if the api accepts an identifier in the request, that led to the failed payment and it was the responsibility of the client to pass the right identifier, then you must respond with a 400 - BAD REQUEST.

If however, the api is just an intimation from the client to request you to perform some domain actions, and one of the domain actions failed; then there is nothing the client can do about it, and you must return a 5XX, since it is a service failure

500 is generally used for ungraceful error scenarios as a rule of thumb. But if you are ok to term this a server error, then return a 500

502 - is a BAD GATEWAY, wherein your domain services acting as a proxy for your downstream services failed to perform a domain action.

Please choose what fits

Comment: take an instance where the payment failed because the customer exceeded his daily limit. In this scenario, he can surely retry (example provided by @RomanVottner). Wouldn't 400 make more sense in this case?